# Как сделать навигацию по RecyclerView при помощи ChipGroup?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Вот пример приложения "ДоДо пицца" тут сделана навигация по списку, работает на подобие якорных ссылок в Web-е, если нажимать на "чипы" выбора на верхней горизонтальной панели, то будет происходить скролл на нужный раздел, если скроллить вручную, то на верхней панели чипы будут переключаться на текущий раздел.

Из того что я уже сделал, я использовал OnCheckedChangeListener у ChipGroup для навигации по RecyclerView, но вот при ручном скролле не могу грамотно обновить ChipGroup, чтобы поставить актуальный раздел, все впадает в шизофрению, то чипы слетают, то список прокручивается...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]